# React-native shadow not appearing in the app screens

Tags: javascript, react-native, shadow

I am working on the React-native App. Earlier the shadow working fine but now in the whole app, the shadow is not visible.

I know there are so many questions and solutions available on StackOverflow. I have tried everything but nothing works for me.

I have tried to add the `backgroundColor` like this:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
shadow: {
  shadowOffset: { width: 10, height: 10 },
  shadowColor: 'black',
  shadowOpacity: 1,
  elevation: 3,
  // background color must be set
  backgroundColor : "#0000" // invisible color
}
```

I have also removed the `overflow: 'hidden'` ;

But no impact on the code.

I am using `elevation` for the android. And it's not working on any of the app screens. If someone facing the same issue please share the solution. TIA

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
   {
        paddingVertical: 12,
        marginTop: 20,
        marginBottom: 70,
        width: '100%',
        borderColor : 'gray', 
        borderWidth : 0.1,
        paddingHorizontal : 12,
        backgroundColor : '#fff',
        margin:8,
        width:'60%',
        alignItems : 'center',
        shadowOpacity: 0.25,
        shadowRadius: 2,
        shadowOffset: {
            width: 0,
            height: 2,
        },
        shadowColor: '#000000',
        elevation: 4,
    }
```

Comment: Thanks But it's not working In my app. I think the issue with the whole app. It's not working on any of the screens. Earlier it was working fine.

Comment: try once with this https://ethercreative.github.io/react-native-shadow-generator/

Comment: Yes, your code is working fine in the other app. But in my app, there is some issue that's why the elevation not working anywhere in the app. Any idea about this why elevation is not working.

Answer (score 0):

See below example which i created a Shadow box for both ios and android. i think this will help you.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Dimensions, Platform } from 'react-native';

const screenHieght = Dimensions.get('window').height;
class ShadowBox extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>

        <View style={styles.innerView}>
          <View style={styles.outer}>
            <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>card </Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.outer}>
            <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>card </Text>
          </View>
        </View>

      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = {
  innerView: {
    borderWidth: 1,
    backgroundColor: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? '#fff' : null,
    borderColor: '#ddd',
    shadowColor: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'green' : '#fff',
    shadowOffset: {
      width: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 3 : 0,
      height: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 3 : 2,
    },
    shadowOpacity: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 1 : 0.8,
    shadowRadius: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? null : 40,
    elevation: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? null : 4,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    width: 300,
    height: 300,
  },
  outer: {
    margin: 10,
    padding: 10,
    alignSelf: 'center',
    borderWidth: 1,
    width: '80%',
    overflow: 'hidden',
  },
};

export default ShadowBox;
```

Feel free for doubts.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But it's not working in my app.